# Angular Router navigate not firing ngOninit

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-routerlink

I'm encountering an issue where the ngOnInit is not firing when returning to a page using the Angular router navigate.

```
//this fires and goes to the /test/parent-route
this.router.navigate(['/test/parent-route']
```

however the ngOnInit does not fire in the component of `parent-route`. The component loads, but ngOnInit does not trigger.

Comment: I'm not familiar with adding a path to the route. what's the purpose of that?

Comment: Apart from the typo's that have been pointed out, you are not giving enough information. Are you trying to route back by any chance? If the component you are routing to is a parent with its own outlet, that component has not been destroyed and it's `ngOnInit` will not be called again.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to route back

Answer (score 2):

Can you post more code?
You wrote `ngOninit` instead of `ngOnInit`.
To make sure you're calling the correct method add `implements OnInit` to your component (add OnInit in import from @angular/core)

```
import { OnInit} from '@angular/core';

...
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
   ngOnInit() {
       // your code here
   }
}
```